# Change background depending on data (Vue3)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am making a weather app but don't understand why my code doesn't change background image.

Codepen of app: https://codepen.io/Link0w0/pen/ZEeBaOj

Code I added to change background:

```
<div id="app" :class="typeof weather.main != 'undefined' && weather.main.temp > 16 ? 
    'warm' : ''">
```

```
  #app.warm {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581205135021-fbad89f942a6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2894&q=80')
     background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Is `weather` available when you load the component? If not, it will crash trying to access the property main of undefined, and never change your class. For complex checks like this it is better to take this JS code out of your template and into a computed property that computes the class, you'll have more control that way.

Comment: Even removing the logic to `<div id="app" class="warm">`, it seems the class isn't applied to the tag.

Comment: That is strange, it seems even just hard coding the `warm` class doesn't update the CSS...

Comment: That's because the first closing `</div>` tag is on the wrong position. Take a look at my  answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your code on codepen:

1. Change

```
<div id="app" :class="typeof weather.main != 'undefined' && weather.main.temp > 16 ? 'warm' : ''">
```

to

```
<div id="app" :class="weather.main && weather.main.temp > 16 ? 'warm' : ''">
```

2. You have a closing `</div>` directly afterwards the `<div id="app" ...` snippet. Move this closing tag after the closing `</main>` tag.

Here ist a working example with a mocked `weather` object:
https://codepen.io/sandmaan/pen/oNZBbYY

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the :class logic with below code

```
<div id="app" :class="{warm: weather.main && weather.main.temp > 16}">
    <!-- rest of code -->
</div>
```

In the CSS part you can replace #app.warm to .warm

```
  .warm {
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581205135021-fbad89f942a6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2894&q=80')
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
  }
```